# How to use Firestore Maps and Arrays and apply them to a TableView

Tags: uitableview, google-cloud-firestore, uikit

I have a document in Firestore which has an Array of Maps..... which I am finding difficult to work with.  I have setup "Codable Struct's" per the recommended.  and I can get a snapshot of the document in question no problem.  below.

```swift
struct specificTourny : Codable, Identifiable {
    @DocumentID var id: String?
    var docuID: String
    var poolstates: [pool]?
    var poolGames: [match]?
    var poolDescription: String
    var brackDescription: String
}
struct match : Codable, Hashable {
    var gameNumber: Int
    var date: String
    var time: String
    var location: String
    var fieldNumber: Int
    var teamA: String
    var teamAuid: String
    var teamAscore: Int
    var teamB: String
    var teamBuid: String
    var teamBscore: Int
}
```

My problem/question is when I use the data from the second Struct, "match", in lets say a tableview where I want to get a count of "match"s or even display that parsed data on a tableview from the second struct is not accessible via dot Notation?  I am also not able to get a count of these individual match's either?

like so....

```swift
// for updating the cell text with information from my db.
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cellz = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "PoolCell", for: indexPath) as! PoolTableViewCell
    cell.TeamName.text = "\(myArray[match.indices].teamA)"

// for getting the total number of matches I have stored in the doc to set my number of rows.
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return myArray[match].gameNumber.count
```

I know there must be a simple way to reference the data that is being Parsed! really I am looking for something like this to apply to the struct within the struct..

```swift
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "myTeamsOnOff", for: indexPath) as! SettingsTableViewCell
    cell.teNames.text = "\(myArray[indexPath.row].teamname)"
```

I have tried a lot of different solutions with no way forward.

adding an image of my db struct

[image]

Comment: Show a minimal reproducible code that shows all relevant info, see: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example
 What is `myArray`? There is no `teamname` in `match`. Use the swift convention to declare your structs with uppercase, like: 'struct Match`. See also this link to understand arrays: https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/CollectionTypes.html

Comment: This isn’t SwiftUI. It’s Swift and UIKit.

Comment: myArray is just an array created from the snapshot of a document I have created in from Firestore's db.  The last set of code is a part of a working tableView where I can reference a struct.  What I am trying to understand, is does Firestore have a way to reference a position in an map that is in a set of arrays?  That way I can point to it in my tableView much like you would an other struct created with Codable format.

Comment: I also added a image of my db to show how the information in put int my db.

Comment: I had to get the information from Firestore in a different form before I could apply it to my table view.  molding the data from firestore seems to have been the key here!